# Redirection Server in Docker With Python

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I am trying to set up a simple redirection server using docker with python3. I have written the server script and copied it in the `/home/app` directory of the container. When I am executing the script via `sh` shell I am able to do so but when I am trying to do it using `CMD` it's throwing an error that the file is not present.

```
FROM python:rc-alpine3.13
USER root 
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --chown=root:root ./ ./
#RUN chmod +x Redir_Server.py
CMD ["python3", "Redir_Server.py"]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What's the actual error?  Have you verified that the contents of the image are what you expect?

Comment: Yes, when i am doing docker run -it <id> sh , and executing command its working also file are present inside the container.  Below is the actual error ```python3: can't open file '/home/app/Redir_Server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```

Comment: I'm suspecting a permission problem, can you add the output of running `RUN ls -la` and `RUN whoami` so we can see the file meta at the dockerfile runtime end? also no need to `RUN mkdir -p /home/app`, if the directory doesnt exist the `WORKDIR` command will create it by itself :)

Comment: `whoami` output is `root` and below is output for `ls la` 

`total 16
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul  4 06:36 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul  4 06:38 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           228 Jul  4 06:36 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           388 Jul  3 09:00 Redir_server.py`